# Detect paywall through Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a Google Chrome extension (and possible support for Firefox and Safari) that displays a brief summary of the page the user is reading. The extension detects the url from the browser's tab, sends it to the backend app server, which creates a summary and returns the response back. There's some more backend machine learning analysis that is being done on the content (hence the need for backend app server).

During my local testing, I found that my extension is showing summaries for pages which are also behind paywalls e.g. NYTimes. **I want to respect the paywalls.** So my question is, **is there a way for my extension to detect if the url is behind a paywall - and then respect it?** I believe this can be achieved through the use of cookies - but I'm not entirely sure how to have a generalized solution.

Comment: Every site does paywalls differently so doubt there is a generic solution.

Comment: What are some of the ways to detect it? From the query path? Cookies? Make a test GET request and expect a different response from the URL? I guess understanding how websites implement paywalls will help.

Comment: Every developer does it differently, hit some paywalls and find out. Some apply CSS to the page, others redirect, others do not send down all the content...